# ADFS WIA: can't get access to domain site using redirects and adfs/ls/wia auth

Tags: python, windows, crm, adfs

Trying to log in some site. I have username, password, domain. Also I registered client(app) , so now there is also client ID.

The question is - I wanna do it using python script, and interest result - code 200. Can someone explain me how doe it work? Should I get some token or anything else?

Scheme step-by-step:

1. https://SOME_DOMAIN_SITE/ - starting point.
2. Redirect to https://{site}/adfs/ls/wia?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm={site}f&wctx={}&wct={date}&wauth=urn%3afederation%3aauthentication%3awindows => here I should enter login and password.
3. After step 2 - I logged in.

I tried Postman and requests module, it always returns 401. Sometimes starting page, where typed 'Error'. But all attempts to do it using Browser are successful.

Also as an option I used this url to get a token - https://{}/adfs/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={}&redirect_uri=https://{} , but it doesn't work.

crm version - 2016 onpremise